# Upgrading XAMPP on Windows from very old version: Can I exclude the native tables without loosing important data?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, xampp

XAMPP has changed from InnoDB to MariaDB some time ago. As I need a newer version of PHP and MySQL I need the new version of XAMPP. Now my database dump of the old XAMPP is very big as all past projects are within this DB.

It looked like I had problems with importing  the native mysql tables

> - information_schema
> - mysql
> - performance_schema
> - phpmyadmin
> - test

Therefore I did the following in the old xampp installation:

First export all database names except the native ones:

```
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema','phpmyadmin','test');
```

Second dump all databases except the native ones:

```
mysqldump -u root > all-dbs.sql --databases db1 db2 .....
```

In the next step I imported the dump within PHPMyAdmin which seems to work (import still running while writing this).

Now my question is: Do the native tables of mysql contain important data of my old projects or can I safely go on with the new ones?

Comment: All those native tables should be ignored when you save your databases, except maybe `test` if you ever used it. All the others are relaterd to how MYSQL looks after itself

Comment: You will need to export the user accounts from MySQL, here is a couple of suggestions on how to do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23519797/how-to-export-import-existing-user-with-its-privileges